# Special \relax definition in the unravel package

Tags: tex-core

The `unravel` package defines an `\__unravel_special_relax:` command, for which we find in the documentation the following:

> A special marker slightly different from `\relax` (its `\meaning` is `\relax` but it differs from `\relax` according to `\ifx`). In the right-hand side of our assignment, `\__unravel_special_relax:` could be replaced by any other expandable command.
>
> ```
> \exp_after:wN \cs_new_eq:NN
> \exp_after:wN \__unravel_special_relax:
> \exp_not:N \__unravel_special_relax:
> ```

How exactly is `\__unravel_special_relax:` different from `\relax`? What is the trick behind this definition? And why is this special `\relax` version needed in the `unravel` package?

Answer (score 7):

If we show the definition in old money:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\let\expandafter\zrelax\noexpand\zrelax
\show\zrelax
\show\relax

\ifx\relax\zrelax
 \show Y
\else
 \show N
\fi

\end{document}
```

produces a terminal output of

```
> \zrelax=\relax.
l.6 \show\zrelax

? 
> \relax=\relax.
l.7 \show\relax

? 
> the letter N.
l.12  \show N

? x
```

so `\zrelax` shows as `\relax` but is `ifx` not equal to `\relax`.  It is the (normally) internal frozen temporary "relax"definition that is used to implement `\noexpand` which makes the command act like an unexpandable `\relax` token just temporarily for one expansion step, but Bruno's trick here grabs that definition with the `\expandafter` and `\let` construct,

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this special `\relax` is needed/in what situations it is useful?

Comment: @siracusa it's never useful in anything approaching normal code, but Bruno needs it as unravel tries to emulate tex execution and that's what tex adds, frozen `\relax` get used in other places as well as `\noexpand` in particular some uses of missing branches in if tests.